# trying to map multiple objects to same location in array

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary

I'm trying to solve a problem that I'm going to explain as follows:

I have an array that I want to hold a type I'm calling "set". This set contains a list of n items of a particular type. I want to be able to **uniformly** map items of a particular type to a particular set (using a key related to the data), but I want that set to be able to hold up to n items, so I need to be able to have several items be mapped to a particular array location (essentially, I want collisions to occur). I first though it'd be easy using a Dictionary, but then I thought: a dictionary will map a key to a particular slot, but if there is a collision, it will use chaining (essentially what I want to do, except I want to limit the number of chains to n), and each chain in a bucket will be of type set..so this means that I'll never be able to have multiple objects of the data I'm storing in any particular set, it will essentially be a bunch of sets containing 1/n of their capacity to hold items of that type.

If this makes sense, can anyone give me any ideas as to how I could achieve what I want? I thought maybe I could use GetHashCode for each type im holding and then use modulus arraySize but apparently GetHashCode won't be useful unless I create my own implementation of it, and the objects I want to stored aren't going to be created by me, so I don't think that will work.

If anyone can give me any ideas, or needs me to clarify, please let me know.

Comment: Maybe `List<List<Whatever>>` or `Dictionary<Key, List<Whatever>>` or something. "A bunch of things in the same location" is a collection, and we get lots of those for free from the framework. Build the storage out of off-the-shelf containers, and have a private instance of the storage thing in your own class. Then write your own public methods that enforce your rules when the consumer adds ore removes items. Implement `IEnumerable<Whatever>` and so on as needed. Don't use arrays for anything. They've been obsolete since the heyday of the Corded Ware Culture.

Comment: So I _think_ what you're after is a Dictionary<Key, List<Thing>>, using your key to get the list of Thing instances that are associated with that key, and then checking the current Count of said list, and if there is room for another (given your desired max limit) then add it to that list

Comment: @LordWilmore I think the issue is that for a particular list of things, I don't necessary want all those things to have the same key. I just want their keys to be mapped to the same list.

Comment: @FrostyStraw Collections are reference types. `dict[1] = dict[2] = new List<Whatever>();` Now you have two keys referring to the same list.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Can you expand on that? The way I understand is a key is hashed and then an index is found for it. Each index would contain List<Whatever>, but to handle collisions, there would be chaining. So each "index" will have a list of List<Whatever>, meaning each key would be mapped to its own List of that list of List<Whatever>s

Comment: @FrostyStraw What's the index for? What are you indexing? The dictionary is `key -> list`. No index.

Comment: Isn't that how hash tables work? The position where a value will be placed in the "backing array" of a hash table will be an index computed based on a hash of its key. If multiple keys are mapped to the same index, chaining will occur to handle these collisions - that means each key will have its own "link" on that chain, where each link will represent the value part of the Dictionary<key,value> - in this case it would be a List<Whatever>

Comment: @FrostyStraw Use a dictionary of lists. What's the "backing array"? You should use a List for it, whatever it is. Whatever logic is around it, write code that does that.

Comment: I just...don't get it. How will multiple Items be assigned to the same list? If each key corresponds to one value, and the value *IS A LIST*, then I am not understanding how multiple keys could ever possibly end up in the same list.

Comment: The value *IS A REFERENCE TO A LIST*. You can have multiple references to the same list, as I illustrated above.

Comment: Much of what you say is unclear though: "How will multiple items be assigned to the same list?" -- easy, containing multiple items is the only thing a list does! Unless you mean something counterintuitive by that sentence, which I believe to be the case. "how multiple keys could ever possibly end up in the same list" -- the keys *aren't in* the list, are they? So you must not mean that. There's a lot of guesswork on my part about what those sentences actually signify.

Comment: Maybe you could make a list of ten fictional elements, and their keys, and do a diagram showing the hierarchical key->value relationships you'd like them to have.

Comment: Items defined as (value, key): (a, 1), (b, 1), (c, 1), (d, 2), (e, 2), (f, 3). Let's say a list is limited to two items. So when you retrieve stuff for key=1, you get a list of [a, b] and a list of [c]. When you retrieve stuff for key=2, you get a list of [c, d]. For key=3, you get a list of [3]. If you add an item (g, 2), that should create a second list under key=2, so retrieving key=2 will now fetch [c, d] and [g]. That's my understanding of your requirements. Is it a close guess, or wildly wrong?

Comment: ok so I can see how what I say is unclear. So I want to store data, but I want to be able to look it up based on a key related to that data. I essentially want to store the key and the data together as some sort of key,value pair. However, I want to be able to have a list of n different such key,value pairs. I want a class that we can call "Set", and this set will contain this list of n different key,value pairs. For this set to have a list containing more than one item, multiple keys should be able should get mapped to where this set is so that the set can then add the key,value into its list

Comment: in your example, it seems  the same key can have different data. in my example, each key uniquely identifies one piece of data.

Comment: So are you saying that you want to group a number of items in to one list, and then have multiple keys associating with that same list?

Comment: @LordWilmore yes